getJSON loop in Jquery dosent return all objects
I have a specific problem.
I have one JSON file that contains all JSON files in a folder.
I am iterating through that in a function where i create an array,
I take that array and send it to another function where i for each filename in array 1
Iterate through and get all the keys and values of that JSON.
Ex: function1 , Create array from JSON
this is the JSON
[
{"file":"filename1.json"},
{"file":"filename2.json"}
]

this is the function:
function getFiles(c,sectiontype){ //This function triggers BKND asp to get all the files that is in BKND/Codes/ folder, and push out a JSON file under JSON/Codes/ folder.
    // c is the type of code ASP, PS, CMD 
    $.ajax('BKND/'+sectiontype+'.asp');
    var arrFiles=[];
    $.ajax({
        'async': false, //Set to false so that script waits for JSON to load.
        'url': 'JSON/'+sectiontype+'.json', //URL to where to pick up JSON
        'dataType': "json", //datatype
        'success': function (data) { //if it succeeds
            cFiles = data
        }
    });
    putCodeblocks(cFiles)
}

this is the second function where i take the array from first function and iterate through each file anc collect all keys and values and put create the codeblocks in HTML
function putCodeblocks(files){
    let zfiles = files.toString();
    console.log(zfiles)
    $.each(obj, function(key,value) {
      $.getJSON('BKND/Codes/'+value.file, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            console.log(element.title)
        })
      })
    }); 

}

The first function works. it creates a JS array object, and i have checked that it is transferred to second function...
But in second function, i only get the first filename and then the $.each loop stops?
why?- What am i missing here?
EDIT: i changed somethings. but get the same result..
function getFiles(c,sectiontype){ //This function triggers BKND asp to get all the files that is in BKND/Codes/ folder, and push out a JSON file under JSON/Codes/ folder.
    // c is the type of code ASP, PS, CMD 
    $.ajax('BKND/'+sectiontype+'.asp');
    var arrFiles=[];
    $.ajax({
        'async': true, //Set to false so that script waits for JSON to load.
        'url': 'JSON/'+sectiontype+'.json', //URL to where to pick up JSON
        'dataType': "json", //datatype
        'success': function (data) { //if it succeeds
            putCodeblocks(data)
        }
    });
    
}

function putCodeblocks(files){   
    console.log(files)
    $.each(files, function(key,value) {
      $.getJSON('BKND/Codes/'+value.file, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            console.log(element.title)
        })
      })
    }); 

}


$.ajax is asynchronous ... whatever needs doing, do it in success  callback - oh, wait, you're doing this with 'async': false - your second function does $.each(obj ... with no indication at all what obj actually is

Remove the 'async': false, and move putCodeblocks(cFiles) into the success function

Both Jaromanda X and mplungjan make excellent remarks.. obj was an old code that i forgot to remove.. and i have moved the call to the function in the success part of function 1

console.log(files) gives me all files in JSON where i just want filenames.
But: the $.each loop just gives me the key from the first file in the array

What does console.log(files.length) give you?  If it's 56 (given your example) or just not the number of files (2 in your example) then you have a JSON string, not an object.

Can you provide a snippet that demonstrates the issue without needing the $.ajax calls?   eg: https://jsfiddle.net/mf0ovzLg/

console.log(files.length) gives me 2, there are two objects in that array.. but im not sure that i am doing that right.. perhaps i need to create an array with just the filenames and not the keys?

"in second function, [I] only get the first filename and then the $.each loop stops" - in your updated code, you're only debugging on the success: callback.  Add another console.log in the $.each and before $.getJSON (so it's the same as the fiddle link above).  Assuming you then get two outputs there: monitor the network tab of the browser to see each request to /Codes/  - if one's a 404 for example, then it won't go in the success callback and you won't get that element.title log.  Consider changing $.getJSON to a $.ajax call with success: and error: callbacks.

I've put everything in a single function.
First I do a single iteration and creates an array with just the filenames.
Then in the second iteration i collect the JSON elements from the actual file.
function getCodeFiles(c,sectiontype){ //This function triggers BKND asp to get all the files that is in BKND/Codes/ folder, and push out a JSON file under JSON/Codes/ folder.
    // c is the type of code ASP, PS, CMD 
       $.ajax('BKND/'+sectiontype+'.asp');
       let arrFilez = []
       $.getJSON('JSON/'+sectiontype+'.json', function(filez){
        $.each(filez, function(key,value) {
            arrFilez.push(value.file)
            });
            
        $.each(arrFilez, function(key, filename){            
            $.getJSON('BKND/Codes/'+filename, function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    //console.log(value.title);
                    var codeTtl = value.title
                    var codeDsc = value.desc
                    var codeLnk = 'files/'+value.link
                    $('#PS').append($(
                        '<div class="codeblock">'
                        +'<span class="codeheader"><div class="codetype ps">'+c+'</div>'+codeTtl+'</span>'
                        +'<span class="content smalldesc">'
                        +'<div class="code">'
                        +'<desc>'+codeDsc+'</desc>'
                        +'<button class="mini ui blue icon button" title="open code in new window" data-href="'+codeLnk+'" data-title="'+codeTtl+'" id="codebutton"><i class="code icon"></i></button>'
                        +'</div>'
                        +'</span>'
                        +'</div>'
                    ));
                });
            });
        }); 
    });    
}

